# proof that this series is not differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $a \in ]0,1[,\; b \in \mathbb{N}$\ $ \{0;1\},$ with  $b$ uneven, $\;ab > 1 + \frac{3}{2} \pi,$ and $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n\cos(b^n \pi x ), x \in \mathbb{R}. $

To show is that the Series is not differentiable in $x=0$ in $3$ steps:

(i) look at the difference quotient for $x_m:= b^{-m}, $

(ii) Split the series in $ 0\leq n \leq m-1 $ and $ m \leq n, $

(iii) estimate skillfully.

The problem is I don't know  what the first step means by setting $x_m:= b^{-m}$.

If I differentiate $f $ I get:

$ f'(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} - \pi a^n b^n \sin( \pi b^n x) $

Can anyone give me a hint so I can finish this task? :-)

Comment: Do you know the difference quotient?

Comment: yes, its $ lim_{x \rightarrow} x_0 \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} $

Comment: Great! Now pick $x_0 = 0$ and consider the sequence given in (i).